# Acceso a datos de servicio Angular 5

Tags: angular4

¿Por qué sólo me permite acceder a los datos de una forma concreta?

Tengo un servicio:

```
getCvs() : Observable<Array<Cv>>{
    return this._http.get<Array<Cv>>(this.url + 'getCvs').pipe(
        tap(cvs => this.log('Fetched CVs'))
    );
}
```

El cual me devuelve un array de Cv. El caso es que solo me deja acceder a la respuesta mediante la función del componente de esta manera:

```
getCvs(){
    this._cvService.getCvs().subscribe(response => {
        this.cvs = response['cvs'];
    });
}
```

Y este es el metodo de la API:

```
function getCvs(req, res){
    if (req.params['id']) {
        var id = req.params['id'];
        Cv.findById(id, (err, cv) => {
            if (err) { res.send({message: 'Error en el servidor.'}); }
            return res.send({message: 'Cv:', cv:cv});       
        });
    }else{
        Cv.find({}, (err, cvs) => {
            if (err) { res.send({message: 'Error en el servidor.'}); }
            return res.send({cvs:cvs});
        });
    }
}
```

El caso es que si yo en la parte de angular pongo:

```
getCvs(){
        this._cvService.getCvs().subscribe(response => {
            this.cvs = response.cvs; <---esto cambio
        });
    }
```

También recibo los datos, pero angular me da error de que cvs no existe en el tipo Cv[];

¿Porqué solo puedo acceder de esta manera sin que angular 5 me de error?

He estado mirando la documentación de angular 5 de HttpClient, etc. Y no he hallado la solución. Incluso en la documentación existen los ejemplos en los que me he basado y no he tenido ese tipo de problema.
Gracias.

Comment: La salida es diferente en función del parámetro id , ¿te pasa en ambos casos? que te sale por consola en response, un objeto o un array directo? el pipe no le veo el sentido

Comment: Me sale un array. El pipe lo tengo hecho simplemente por un servicio de mensajes, similar al que tienen como ejemplo en la documentación de Angular. Era simplemente por practicarlo. Lo que me devuelve es un array de objetos Cv.

Comment: ¿ podrías mostrar que imprime "response.cvs" ?

Comment: No mostraba ninguna respuesta de la que se pudiera aprovechar nada, es más, mostraba un error si accedia a "response.cvs" de esa manera. Tenía que utilizar "response['cvs']" para obtener los datos. El error era algo así como: cvs no existen en el tipo Cv[].